# Which is more efficient/more conventional?

Tags: java, performance, user-interface, components, addition

Which of the following is a better way to add [Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) to a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)?

```
panel.add(jlist);
panel.add(jcombobox);
panel.add(jmenu);
```

or

```
addComponents(new Component[] { jlist, jcombobox, jmenu }, panel);


    private static void addComponents(Component[] component, JPanel panel) {
         for (Component loop : component) {
              panel.add(loop);
         }
    }
```

Comment: performance shouldn't even be a consideration for something like this...

Comment: ... I think I'm going to flag this as not constructive.

Comment: Amir Afghani: Efficiency can relate to typing efficiency (fewer keystrokes) or mental efficiency (which one is easier to read).

Comment: As the other commenters have alluded, you need to define "better" for this to be a viable Stack Overflow question. It's not helpful for everyone to approach this with personal definitions of good and bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first. Why?

What if at some point you would like to pass another argument to your panel.add(...) statement for each component? If you have a loop you cannot easily do this.

For example, using MigLayout (but it works for other situations as well):

```
panel.add(jlist, new CC().width("40%").span());

panel.add(jcombobox, new CC().width("60%"));

panel.add(jmenu, new CC().width("20%").span());
```

Only the first way allows for this.